# vuetify v-text-field prevent height change when showing error/message

Tags: vuetify.js

When a message or error message is applied to a v-text-field (commonly as a result of form validation) the hight of the element changes slightly.  Is there an easy / clean way to avoid this?

The issue is easily observed in the "Password Input" section examples of the [Vuetify official docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/text-fields#password-input). Just click back and forth between the two text inputs labeled "Normal with hint text" and "Not visible":

[image]

Update:
Overriding vuetify's css styling solves the problem:

```
.v-messages__message {
    line-height: 12px;
}
```

But seems like a very brittle solution.

Comment: Instead of change the default Vuetify class you can create your own class and put this in the scoped CSS on the file to avoid future problems after new releases/updates.